# How to get a screen shot using flash?

Tags: flash

I need a function that a user can just click a flash app button in the browser and then submit his screen shot to a server side script.But it seems difficult to find a solution.Any suggestion will be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like this should not even be possible - it would be a serious security loophole if it were.

Comment: I see this problem,thanks.But any other available way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PLEASE no solution.

Why?

Because it would mean every stupid little flash app (on any nontrusted website) could see what I do on my screen.

Which, incidentally, would be a HUGH security risk.

Comment: While I agree to the sentiment, and there probably isn't a native flash solution anyway, security through obscurity is no security at all and this 'answer' is not really an answer to the question as it stands.

Comment: You're totally right.And any other way to do this function?Thanks.

Comment: This is no "security through obscurity". it is "you are not trusted and dont ahve to watch me surfing". This is "keeping confidential information confidential". Like bank information - account statements, with numbers, addresses etc. Basic privacy, coxymla.

No way from Flash, thank heaven.